# Objective C - static variables in categories

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, ios5, categories

I do have a little Problem.
Since my UIViewControlles are all named in the same scheme:

MyView1Controller.h
MyView1Controller.m
MyView1.xib

MyView2Controller.h
MyView2Controller.m
MyView2.xib

MyView3Controller.h
MyView3Controller.m
MyView3.xib

I would now prefer to init my UIViewControllers via a factory method.
Therefore I would implement a Cateogry on UIViewController:

```
static NSString *standardNibFileName;

@interface UIViewController (FactoryInstantiation)

+ (id) standardViewController;

@end
```

And in MyView1Controller controller I would declare the static nib file name variable:

```
static NSString *standardNibFileName = @"MyView1";

@implementation MyView1Controller
```

Then I could instantiate all my UIViewCOntrollers using the method:

```
@implementation UIViewController (FactoryInstantiation)

+ (id) standardViewController;
{
    if(standardNibFileName != nil) {

        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
        Class classToIntantiate = NSClassFromString(className);
        return [[classToIntantiate alloc] initWithNibName:className bundle:nil];
    }

return nil;
}

@end
```

Init:

```
MyView1Controller *a = [MyView1Controller standardViewController];
```

But the static variable is always nil.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your category, check if the static is nil, and, if so, init it.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
What do you mean by init it? I do not have the name of the nib file in the category. And I do not want to "calculate" the name by editing the name of NSStringFromClass and so on...

Comment: the reason the static is nil is because you haven't initialized the class yet.  I wonder if you used a #define instead of a static var if that would solve your problem?

Comment: no it doesn't work either.
I thought in IOS5 there is the possibility to declare properties in categories...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a + method instead on `UIViewController` class and override on the implementing classes

```
+ (NSString*) getStandardNibFileName {
    return @"nibName"
}
```

Edit: If the implementing class has the same nibName as the base you don't have to override the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah, that's what I thought first, but then I'll have to implement this method in every viewcontroller. Isn't there a much easier way outside?

Comment: Well.. you are declaring the static variable outside the implementation which means it doesn't belong to any class but when you #import the .h file you will get the static variable aswell.

Comment: Another solution is to define a string in the .h for every ViewControll like this: #define sNibName @”nibName”

Comment: if i'm following this right, if you did create the + method you could then just create a base view controller that your MyViewControllers would inherit from.  This way you only have to do the getStandardNibFileName logic once.

Comment: Yes. you can put the + getStandardNibFileName in the base and if the nibname is the same as the base you dont have to implement it again

Comment: @carbonbasednerd 
Thanks for your answer!  The problem is that I don't really want to inherit all Controllers from one BaseController. It's not as easy to use and flexible as the category method (if it's possible to get it working ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have static NSString *standardNibFileName; in .h file as well, give a try removing it, I hope 
static NSString *standardNibFileName = @"MyView1"; .m is more than enough

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it the category implementation cannot compile without knowing the static variable. I could declare it in the .m file, but then, again it'll be nil...